# Conditionally passing key value pairs doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've got and object where I want conditionally pass key value pairs.
For reasons unknown to me, the condition is not being triggered.
In my object. Any idea why?
I think that the propblem is in the objects structure?

```
const src = "test";
const traffic_source ="test1";
const utm_campaign = "test2";
const utm_content = "tes3t";
const utm_medium = "test4";
const utm_source = "test5";
const purpose = "Consolidation";
const acknowledgement = 'acknowledgement';

const eligibility = {
  // utm values
  src,
  traffic_source,
  utm_campaign,
  utm_content,
  utm_medium,
  utm_source,
  ...(purpose === 'Consolidation' && acknowledgement),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The right side of the `&&` needs to be something that the `...` can spread into the object - that is, it should be an object with a `acknowledgement` property, not a string:

```js
const src = "test";
const traffic_source ="test1";
const utm_campaign = "test2";
const utm_content = "tes3t";
const utm_medium = "test4";
const utm_source = "test5";
const purpose = "Consolidation";
const acknowledgement = 'acknowledgement';

const eligibility = {
  // utm values
  src,
  traffic_source,
  utm_campaign,
  utm_content,
  utm_medium,
  utm_source,
  ...(purpose === 'Consolidation' && { acknowledgement }),
};
console.log(eligibility);
```

Your existing code is spreading the string into the object, resulting in `eligibility` containing not only `src`, `traffic_source`, etc, but also

```
0: 'a',
1: 'c',
2: 'k',
3: 'n',
...
```

because those are the properties of the string.